# Trying to checkout file from svn using java code(svn cli)

Tags: java, svn, tortoisesvn, command-line-interface

This is what I am trying to do:
1) Take SVN url as input from user
2) Take svn username as input
3) Take svn username as input
4) Take Directory path where checkout needs to be done as input

Now, I am passing a checkout command to my cmd prompt through java code.Somehow, my file if not getting checked out through java code, but on running the same command on cmd prompt I am able to checkout the file.PFB the code I am running.

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

rt.exec("cmd.exe /c start "+"svn co 'http://Testing//ITS_R2_Final_1.0_14Feb' --    username     12345 --password 'abc@Mar14' --non-interactive", null, new File    ("D://test_svn"));

rt.wait(1700);
```

Please help.

Point to be noted here is that when I dont use non-interactive then it opens up the command prompts for the username and password,once I provide is with the credentials,It checks out fine.

Comment: If you have option to use another library, check http://java.dzone.com/announcements/svnkit-tame-subversion-java

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I would prefer to use the CLI to save the overhead for the library.The project has plenty of jars of its own.

Comment: Plus when the command is running fine on CLI I am sure I am doing some mistake in my code that I cant point out.Need help for the same.

Comment: You have to tell us what is going wrong. Do you get an exception? Do you see the logs of the SVN server? Are there any messages on this log?

Comment: unfortunately, I dont get any error on my Eclipse console.SVN logs just give me teh history/comments of the updated versions.When I run my Java Program the command window just opens for a blink disappears in a second.The main issue is that the checkout is not taking place in the folder specified.Please help

Comment: If anything, invoking the CLI will be *more* overhead than using a library. And it eliminates multiple dependencies (Windows and svn.exe being installed and in `%PATH%`) from your program. Using SVNKit is the right way to go about this.